# How do I get the text value entered by a user inside the input text box element?

Tags: jquery

I have a text box with a default value when the page is loaded:

```
<input id="txtYear" type="text" value="2013" />
```

After the page is loaded, the user can input something else into the text box, e.g. `2014`.

When I try to do this:

```
var year = $("#txtYear").val();
```

The value is still `2013` even though the user changed the text to 2014.

How do I  get the value the user input in this case?

Comment: Are you setting the value of the variable BEFORE the user has time to enter a new value?  You have given *very very* little code to diagnose why the behavior you are experiencing is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the change event to the textbox.

The reason you see that happening is because the code is already executed by the time the user types a new year.

```
$('#txtYear').on('change', function () {
    var year = $("#txtYear").val();
    console.log(year)
}).change();
```

**Refactored**

```
   var $year = $('#txtYear');
    $year.on('change', function () {
        var year = this.value;
        console.log(year)
    }).change();
```

Comment: this did the trick. thanks! i can accept ur answer in 7 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer does trick but if you look at the value in html source it still remains the same as on load time i.e, "2013"

```
var year = $("#txtYear").val();

$("#txtYear").on("change",function(){
    year = $(this).val()
    $(this).attr("value",year);
    alert(year);
});

alert(year);
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wDtRt/